# Copying Emacs configuration to different computer

Tags: latex, config, configuration-files

I configured Emacs on one computer and copied `~/.emacs` to a different computer. That other computer uses a newly installed operating system.

Both computers run Ubuntu 16.04 with the latest updates installed and both run Ecmacs 24.5.1 from the Ubuntu repositories.

When I opened a LaTeX document, I got this warning:

[image]

I created that document on the first computer using Emacs. On that computer, Emacs always puts this in the end of every LaTeX file (after `\end{document}`):

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

There is is suspicious `t`.

I didn't go into Emacs package manager and install anything (like `AUCTeX`) yet, on the computer with the fresh installation. Still, LaTeX files are opened in `LaTeX-mode`.

When I typed a `!` as my response to the warning mentioned above, this was added to `~/.emacs`:

```
 '(safe-local-variable-values (quote ((TeX-master . t))))
```

Then, that warning went away on subsequent attempts. But there isn't even such a warning in the first place on the first computer, even though the `~/.emacs` file was exactly the same.

There are other differences. Like when I press `C-c C-c` in `LaTeX-mode` to build the PDF, on the first computer, that's all that happens. On the new one, a buffer frame and a buffer are created, containing the `pdflatex` command which was used to build the PDF and its console output.

Upon pressing `C-c C-c` on the first computer, the mini buffer says:

```
Command: (default LaTeX)
```

On the second one, it says:

```
Command: (default pdflatex)
```

I understand that `pdflatex` is a program with an equally named package (in Ubuntu) and an equally named command to call it. But why is the default on the first computer `LaTeX`? That is to say: Where is it configured?

Can someone please explain what's going on? If I want the exact same Emacs configuration on both computers, how should I go about it?

---

This is my `~/.emacs` file after the change described above occurred:

```
(set-face-foreground 'minibuffer-prompt "red")


(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)



(defvar-local is-new-file-buffer nil)

(defun save-new-file-before-kill ()
  (when (and (not (buffer-file-name))
             is-new-file-buffer
             (yes-or-no-p 
              "New file has not been saved. Would you like to save before closing?"))
    (call-interactively 'save-buffer)))

(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'save-new-file-before-kill)    

(defun new-file (dir)
  (interactive "DCreate New File In: ")
  (let ((buffer (generate-new-buffer "<Unsaved File>")))
    (switch-to-buffer buffer)
    (setq-local default-directory dir)
    (setq-local is-new-file-buffer t)))

(global-set-key [(f12)] 'new-file)


;; Save all tempfiles in $TMPDIR/emacs$UID/                                     
(defconst emacs-tmp-dir (format "%s/%s%s/" "/t" "emacs" (user-uid)))
(setq backup-directory-alist
      `((".*" . ,emacs-tmp-dir)))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,emacs-tmp-dir t)))
(setq auto-save-list-file-prefix
      emacs-tmp-dir)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(LaTeX-indent-level 4)
 '(LaTeX-item-indent 0)
 '(TeX-brace-indent-level 4)
 '(indent-tabs-mode t)
 '(org-agenda-files
   (quote
    ("~/[I censored this path but it exists on both computers].org" "~/[a different path].org" "~/[and another one].org")))
 '(safe-local-variable-values (quote ((TeX-master . t))))
 '(show-paren-mode t)
 '(tool-bar-mode nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )


;; Bind C-tab to autocompletion in LaTeX-mode.
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda()
        (local-set-key [C-tab] 'TeX-complete-symbol)))

(setq LaTeX-paragraph-commands '("documentclass" "usepackage"))

(setq TeX-auto-save t)
    (setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
    (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
    (setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)

(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)

(setq org-startup-indented t)

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)


;; Don't show welcome screen when opening Emacs.
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)


;; Highlight matching parentheses.
(show-paren-mode 1)



;; Don't clutter the git repo with files by puttem them into a specially named folder.
(defvar org-export-output-directory-prefix "built_files_ignored_by_git_" "prefix of directory used for org-mode export")

(defadvice org-export-output-file-name (before org-add-export-dir activate)
  "Modifies org-export to place exported files in a different directory"
  (when (not pub-dir)
      (setq pub-dir (concat org-export-output-directory-prefix (substring extension 1)))
      (when (not (file-directory-p pub-dir))
       (make-directory pub-dir))))



;; Show line numbers.
(global-linum-mode t)

;; Show column numbers.
(setq column-number-mode t)

;; Agenda view key binding.
(global-set-key [(control ?c) (?a)] 'org-agenda)
```

`/t` (mentioned in the code above) exists on both computers and in both cases is a symlink to a folder (which even is in the exact same location on both systems).

Comment: I stopped reading the remainder of the question when you said you got an error message and then didn't tell us *exactly* what it was ...  Consider setting `(setq debug-on-error t)` at the outset of your user-configuration and post the error message . . .  The error and/or `*Backtrace*` buffer messages are generally helpful in debugging problems.

Comment: @lawlist Sorry. I added it to the question.

Comment: Your emacs config is more than just your init file. In general, the `~/.emacs.d` directory is your emacs config, with the possible exceptions of (a) the init file itself, which might be `~/.emacs` or similar; and (b) any `site-lisp` files which are on one of the machines but not the other. Note that you can rename `~/.emacs` to `~/.emacs.d/init.el` to put it into your config directory as well.

Answer (score 4):

On the first computer you have AUCTeX installed, on the second one emacs is using its default mode for editing tex files.

Comment: That would make sense and I expected this (which is why I pointed out that I didn't install AUXTeX or any other packages using the package manager on the second computer). Can you tell me why LaTeX documents are opened in  `LaTeX-mode` on the second computer, not in `latex-mode`, `text-mode`, or `fundamental-mode`? Isn't `LaTeX-mode` an AUXTeX thing?

Comment: `latex-mode` is the built in mode for editing tex files in emacs, the AUCTeX one is `TeX-latex-mode`, but the mode line indication is the same for both.

Comment: Oh, you're right. This is completely unexpected for me. So I should probably go about it like this: Move `~/.emacs` to `~/.emacs.d/init.el` on the first computer, than copy that folder over / sync it. Then delete that weird stuff in the LaTeX documents which have it. (I noticed that not all of my LaTeX documents do and I can edit and build them just fine.)